# mongoose-nodejs causing maximum call stack size exceeded, in mongoose save()

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

The problem I'm facing is:

- When uncommenting line1 and uncommenting(logging) line3 and line4 - It stucked there and it doesn't print anything and after some time it gives maximum call stack size exceeded but if I print only string it doesn't give any error..
- I tried all test cases, cause of error is line1 because if I don't do line1 it works smoothly
- Actually I wanted to add  booking in cust(Customer) in bookings array after adding new booking in Booking.

  ```
  async book(req, res, next) {


    const _id=req.body.id 
       /* I am getting this id From Jwt token,
      (for case I am showing as this )*/

    const category = req.params.category


    try {
         const cust = await Customer.findOne(
           { _id: _id }).populate("bookings")

        const booking = new Booking({
            service: category,
            customer: cust
        })

        await booking.save()//line 0

        cust.bookings.push(booking) //line 1

         await cust.save() //line2

        console.log(cust); //line 3
        console.log(booking); //line 4
        console.log("test"); //line 5



        return res.render("status", )

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);

    }
  }
  ```

**This is cust (Customer Schema)**

```
const customerSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
         type: String,

     },
  bookings: [
  {
  type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: 'Booking'
 }]})
```

**This is booking schema(Booking)**

```
const bookingSchema = new Schema({ 
   id: {
    type: String
     },
   service: {
    type: String
    },
    customer: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Customer'
})
```

**So My objective is that ,Whenever booking is added in (Booking model)
for particular customer, so that same booking must be 'ref' (get pushed) in bookings array in customers(Customer) for that only particular customer**

**SO TO ACHIEVE THAT**

- I first save booking in (line 0)
- then I push same booking in bookings(array in cust (Customer)) [line 1]
- and then I save cust(Customer) in [line 2]

> Maximum call stack size exceeded

```
at get (D:\my_proj\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\get.js:8:30)
at isBsonType (D:\my_proj\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\isBsonType.js:10:10)
at clone (D:\my_proj\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\clone.js:75:7)
at cloneObject (D:\my_proj\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\clone.js:125:17)
at clone (D:\my_proj\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\clone.js:60:16)
at cloneObject (D:\my_proj\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\clone.js:125:17)
at clone (D:\my_proj\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\clone.js:60:16)
at cloneObject (D:\my_proj\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\clone.js:125:17)
at clone (D:\my_proj\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\clone.js:60:16)
at cloneObject (D:\my_proj\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\clone.js:125:17)
```

Comment: There are multiple issues in the code, but first: Can you share the model schemas ? and tell us what is the scenario ? and share from where cust gets its value ?

Comment: I added Customer ,Booking schema and also added what was my objective (scenario ),and cust is getting from findOne .(I also added that !)..Problem is that, that when I uncomment Line 1 and then print line 3 or line 4 - It gives that error....but when I Print only string ("test") It get printed and all works smoothly .I did trial with Line2 (line1 commented)  , there is no problem with line 2

Comment: did the answer work with you ?

Comment: its giving error cast error. ObjectId cannot cast to string

Comment: `cust.bookings.push(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(booking._id)) //line 1`

Answer (score 0):

**#1>** because you defined bookings object type in schema as `ObjectId`, but in `line1` you are trying to push an Object.

```
cust.bookings.push(booking) //line 1
```

so try this instead:

```
cust.bookings.push(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(booking._id)) //line 1
```

---

**#2>**

and in this line you need to remove the comma if you will not pass data after.

```
return res.render("status", )
```

and it's better to `res.redirect('/route')` and render the route.

Answer (score 0):

In my own case, setting strict as true on the model works as below works for me
[image]